# Search the documents that were added after specific timestamp-> Elastic Search

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-stack, subquery

I want to search the documents that were added after a specific timestamp in Elastic Search, I have tried 'search_after' and 'from', but nothing seems to work. Is there any way to search after the specific ID or Timestamp?

Comment: Hey could you add you a sample of your documents and the query you tried ? which version of es are you using ?

Comment: have you looked at this ? -> https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-range-query.html

Comment: Hi, I tried range query and it worked, Thanks

`  "query": {
                    "range": {
                "timestamp": {
                    "gte": 1641203425,
                    "lte": 1641280856
                }
                }
                }
Where I used dates as timestamps. Thanks Again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried range query and it worked

```
"query": { "range": 
        { "timestamp": { "gte": 1641203425, "lte": 1641280856 } } }
```

Where I used dates in timestamp format.